# Next value of a tables identity specification - SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

How can I get the next value of the identity specification using SQL Server?

Don't say `Select (id+1) from Table1`, because it gives wrong results when deleting rows.

Comment: Out of interest, why do you think you need this information?

Comment: Using IDENTITY is your way of declaring that you don't care what the ID is. Asking what the next value is in an indication that you shouldn't be using identity at all, or that you've got a different problem that you can solve a better way. Can you explain *why* you need this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, whatever you are doing, you are likely doing something wrong, because concurrency.

But you can get the next value of the identity column using

```
select ident_current('TableName') + ident_incr('TableName')
```

Comment: Wish I could +100 this. There is little reason to want to know the next identity number.

Answer (score 4):

You can't know, and you aren't supposed to try to guess. It's important to rethink your problem. For example, stop using identity and generate your own IDs, or switch to something like `uniqueidentifier` instead, which you can control and won't clash between threads.

The identity value of the next record isn't deterministic. Consider this code;

```
begin tran
insert into table values ('my new value')
rollback tran
```

Even though this code doesn't insert a record, it will update the next ID generated, and cause a gap. So if the table were at max ID=4, then you run this code, then you do a insert which you commit, the ID of that record will be 6, not 5.

Because SQL Server controls this value, your predictions will be right only until your system hits more load, or people do advanced things like use transactions.

Its a classic source of problems, so avoid doing it.

An alternative, if you want to control IDs, is to use something like a HILO generator -- [This RavenDB document](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/csharp/client-api/document-identifiers/hilo-algorithm) explains the principle of the idea.